How to solve the divergence error in dblquad python
Any help to double integrate this function probably in python:

Becaue when I run the following code it gives an error:
 IntegrationWarning: The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent.

I try to integrate a function f(k,t1) then plot it versus the variable k (in the python file $\tau$ is $t_1$)
But the function dominator may contain some singularity which gives divergences meanwhile the integration, so I appreciate any help to solve the error of divergence and run the code.
Here is the code that I use , now it freezes after giving errors:
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.special import kn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time, sys

k=3;a=0.1;nab=10**-9;n=0.94;kz= 0.002;
# Define the function to be integrated
def f(m,t1,k):
    return (-(50*t1**2*(-16*(16 + 20*t1 + 6*t1**2 + 4*t1**3 + 3*t1**4) + (1 + t1)**2*(448 + 1568*t1 + 2400*t1**2 + 1920*t1**3 + 864*t1**4 + 240*t1**5 + 72*t1**6 + 42*t1**7 + 18*t1**8 + 3*t1**9)*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1))) + m*(1 + t1)*(-128 + 1536*t1**2*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 2112*t1**4*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 1008*t1**5*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 312*t1**6*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 114*t1**7*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 60*t1**8*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 21*t1**9*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 3*t1**10*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)) + 64*t1*(-1 + 6*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1))) + 32*t1**3*(-1 + 78*math.exp((4*(1 + t1))/(2 + t1)))))/(0.01+4.*(1 + t1)*(2 + t1)*(-48 - 96*t1 + 8*(-3 + 2*m**2)*t1**2 + 8*(3 + 2*m**2)*t1**3 + (6 + 4*m**2)*t1**4 + 6*t1**5 + 3*t1**6))) * (50 * t1**2 +k) 

X = np.arange(1,10,0.1)


def F(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i,val in enumerate(x):
        y,err = integrate.dblquad(f, 0.1, 2, lambda x: 0.1, lambda x: 2, args=(val,))
        res[i]= y
    return res

plt.plot(X,F(X))
plt.title("P(k), H=2.5")
plt.xlabel("k")
plt.ylabel("P")
plt.savefig('P(k).png')


This is your third question on the same problem, but you haven't addressed any of the comments in either of your previous questions (question 1 and question 2).

Can you add a higher quality image, inputs and expected outputs? Can you calculate f(m,t1,k) component by component?

@jared. In question (1) you asked for the function formula and I addressed  here. And here the function is not the same as in the previous questions

@user24714692. How  to add latex formula in this forums ? because I think if I added the function latex expression it will be better.

@Dr.phy Image is fine. See here

@Dr.phy My question was about where the function came from to try and get a better idea of its dynamics. What makes you think the integral is convergent?

@user24714692. (Can you calculate f(t1,k) component by component?  ) I calculated the function at arbitrary value of k and t1 , say $t1=1$ and $k=2$ and it gives a definite value. No how to find the singularities points in the function through the whole integration limit and what to do when I find these points that cause divergences.

@jared. Yeah, thanks for asking, the function that I try to integrate and plot is a physical quantity, and I wonder if there is a way to enhance its formula and make python run it. It also gives this error before the code freezes: Extremely bad integrand behavior occurs at some points of the  integration interval.

@Dr.phy And you're sure your function is correct and domain is valid?

With such a horrendous function, it shouldn't really be a surprise you're having problems with numerical integration. But try playing with epsabs or epsrel to see if you get better results.

You may want to replace math.exp with np.exp, so that (in some cases) evaluating of the function can be faster.

@9769953, I think epsabs and epsrel can be used only with quad not with dblquad

These parameters are keyword arguments in the dlbquad function, so they are usable for dblquad.

Hi @9769953. Thanks for drawing my attention to use these parameters with dblquad. As I understand when the number of tolerance decrease , the integration will go faster or the  tolerance error will be avoided, but when I used  epsabs=1.49e-13, epsrel=1.49e-13 in the code, the same errors still appear and the code still freezes .

From the error message, I'm guessing you need to lower the tolerances, not increase them.

Okay, the usual value is 1.49e-8 when i let it 1.49e-13 it means I decreased it
